# How can the CRC checksum give the position where the error occured?

Tags: algorithm, crc

I know how to compute a CRC checksum, and I know a CRC checksum can detect k-1 bit error (k being the length of the checksum). But what I am curious about is how the checksum can so luckily be the position of the error bit.

I know Hamming code; Hamming code is designed so that the 'checksum' gives the position of the error. Yet I have not seen any post explaining why the CRC checksum gives the error bit position.

I read [this](http://einstein.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/papers/CRC-BitfilterEng.pdf);
it explains that "to prove that the receiver can correct this error we only 
have to prove that the residuals can be distinguished from any other distinct single bit errors."

That proves we can map residuals to positions of bit errors, yet does not explain why it happens to be natural order. By natural order I mean `10` indicating position 2, `11` indicating position 3.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) doesn't seem to explain this, and the famous [*A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms*](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html) does not do the trick either.

Could anyone explain or give some references?

Comment: "The engineer's error coding handbook" / A.D. Houghton is one textbook I used. But be prepared for being required to understand some not-quite-trivial math in order to find the answer you are looking for.

Comment: It's not so simple: Some CRCs can detect this, others can detect that, some permit recovery (within limits). Also, the length of the data is limited by the width of the CRC.

Answer (score 2):

@jwodder thank you for making my post more readable.
@Plo_Koon thanks for providing so much relevent information, but I am afraid you do not answer my question: why the residual (or reminder) of CRC can indicate the position of error bit.
@laune thank you for sharing a reference.

I continued search and see [*CRC chapter of hacker's delight*](http://www.hackersdelight.org/crc.pdf) and saw a reference ,so I find the Tanenbaum, Andrew S. Computer Networks 5th edition,`SEC. 3.2 ERROR DETECTION AND CORRECTION` and it dawns on me.

I post my understanding here, hope that helps who don't get why CRC residual can indicate the single bit error position.

Let's resume the correct message that we should receive is T(x), and what we actually received is T(x)+E(x). Each 1 bit in E(x) corresponds to a bit that
has been inverted. Then we divides that by G(x)(the generator) ,that is, we  computes

```
[T(x) + E(x)]/G(x)
```

`T(x)/G(x)` is 0, so the residual we get is `E(x)/G(x)`

If G(x) contains two or more terms (may be this is "some permit recovery (within limits)" menthioned by @laune ), it will never divide into E(x).

That's why we get exactly the position in residual when doing CRC calculation!

Answer (score 0):

The central concept in detecting or correcting errors is
redundancy. To be able to detect or correct errors, we need
to send some extra bits with our data. These redundant bits
are added by the sender and removed by the receiver. Their
presence allows the receiver to detect or correct corrupted
bits. The concept of including extra information in the
transmission for error detection is a good one. But instead of
repeating the entire data stream, a shorter group of bits
may be appended to the end of each unit. This technique is
called redundancy because the extra bits are redundant to
the information: they are discarded as soon as the accuracy
of the transmission has been determined.
Figure 8 shows the process of using redundant bits to
check the accuracy of a data unit. Once the data stream has
been generated, it passes through a device that analyses it
and adds on an appropriately coded redundancy check. The
data unit, now enlarged by several hits, travels over the link to the receiver. The receiver puts the entire stream through
a checking function. If the received hit stream passes the
checking criteria, the data portion of the data unit is
accepted and the redundant bits are discarded.

**Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC)**

The most powerful of the redundancy checking
techniques is the cyclic redundancy check (CRC). 
The CRC is based on polynomial arithmetic, in particular, on computing the
remainder of dividing one polynomial in GF(2) (Galois field with two elements)
by another. 
Unlike the parity check which is based on addition. CRC is based on
binary division. In CRC, instead of adding bits to achieve a
desired parity, a sequence of redundant bits, called the CRC
or the CRC remainder, is appended to the end of a data unit
so that the resulting data unit becomes exactly divisible by a
second, predetermined binary number. At its destination, the
incoming data unit is divided by the same number. If at this
step there is no remainder the data unit is assumed to be
intact and is therefore accepted. A remainder indicates that
the data unit has been damaged in transit and therefore
must be rejected.
The redundancy bits used by CRC are derived by dividing
the data unit by a predetermined divisor; the remainder is
the CRC. To be valid, a CRC must have two qualities: It must
have exactly one less bit than the divisor, and appending it
to the end of the data string must make the resulting bit
sequence exactly divisible by the divisor.
Both the theory and the application of CRC error
detection are straightforward. The only complexity is in
deriving the CRC.

**Performance of CRC**

CRC is a very effective error detection method. If the divisor
is chosen according to the previously mentioned rules,
1.CRC can detect all burst errors that affect an odd number
of bits.
2.CRC can detect all burst errors of length less than or equal
to the degree of the polynomial
3.CRC can detect, with a very high probability, burst errors
of length greater than the degree of the polynomial.

**Correction of errors**

The correction of errors is more difficult than the detection.
In error detection, we are looking only to see if any error
has occurred. The answer is a simple yes or no. We are not
even interested in the number of errors. A single-bit error is
the same for us as a burst error. In error correction, we
need to know the exact number of bits that are corrupted
and more importantly, their location in the message. The
number of the errors and the size of the message are
important factors. If we need to correct one single error in
an 8-bit data unit, we need to consider eight possible error
locations; if we need to correct two errors in a data unit of
the same size, we need to consider 28 possibilities. You can
imagine the receiver's difficulty in finding 10 errors in a data
unit of 1000 bits.

To calculate the number of redundancy bits `r` required to
correct a given number of data bits `m`. we must find a
relationship between `m` and `r`. With `m` bits of data and `r` bits
of redundancy added to them, the length of the resulting
code is `m + r`. If the total number of bits in a transmittable
unit is `m + r`. then `r` must be able to indicate at least
`m+r+1` different states. Of these, one state means no error,
and `m + r` states indicate the location of an error in each of
the `m + r` positions.

So `m+r+1` states must be discoverable by `r` bits: and `r`
bits can indicate `2^r` different states. Therefore `2^r` must be
equal to or greater than `m+r+1`:

`2^r=>m+r+1`

For example, if the value of m is 7 (as in a 7-bit ASCII
code), the smallest `r` value that can satisfy this equation is
4:

`2^4=>7+4+1`

**Hamming Code**

Hamming provides a practical solution. The Hamming code
can be applied to data units of any length and uses the
relationship between data and redundancy bits discussed
above. For example, a 7-bit ASCII code requires 4
redundancy bits that can be added 10 the end of the data
unit or interspersed with the original data bits. In Figure 17,
these bits are placed in positions 1, 2 ,4, and 8 (the
positions in an 11-bit sequence that are powers of 2).

See this links for info and examples (all info above is from 1 link):
[1](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CGYQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uotechnology.edu.iq%2Fdep-eee%2Flectures%2F4th%2FCommunication%2FInformation%2520theory%2F6.pdf&ei=51nLU4uKIoLnywPevYCAAw&usg=AFQjCNGIU6SxMSEWQ-3q7TSkRH_dvJdHUg&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGQ),
[2](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CG4QFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cssancl.org%2Fbbs%2Findex.php%3Fattachments%2Flectures9-12-pdf.1872%2F&ei=51nLU4uKIoLnywPevYCAAw&usg=AFQjCNGItulA42-1Za96Q6GX69XbLtJJxw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGQ),
[3](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CE0QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hackersdelight.org%2Fcrc.pdf&ei=51nLU4uKIoLnywPevYCAAw&usg=AFQjCNH2vUuy9S9Jl4hBhKKGT2duANg2Nw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGQ&cad=rjt).